# When saved to activities, tokens inside emails are not evaluated

Tags: activities, tokens

Is it normal that when a reminder email goes out and is saved as an activity that tokens are not evaluated and saved in the activity?

If that is normal, where is the best place to make a feature request? The value of the activities feature is significantly reduced when tokens are not evaluated when stored in activities.

If that is *not* normal behavior, any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I think that is expected behaviour - but I agree it is not desirable in terms of confirming what is actually be sent out (are tokens actually being filled, what data got sent to X, etc). I checked with Eileen about this to which she replied "no good reason it can't I expect". But it is a new feature request so to speak. If you have some resources to put towards a fix eg skills/funds then it could get properly scoped.

Comment: Hi, if you send an email to several contacts, it will save it as a single activity, so not sure how to avoid saving it with the token. An alternative might be to offer the option to replace the token by the data of the contact **when viewing it** (so if data change between it's been sent and viewed, it will be a problem, but otherwise might make it easier to read the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is normal behavior. Feature requests can be made on the forums or if there is funding, via the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).